# How to use latest version of MSAL.NET with authorization code flow in ASP.NET MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-msal

I need to implement Azure AD authentication and authorization for my ASP.NET MVC web application using MSAL.NET with authorization code flow and I need to call my own API.
I can see a lot of manual code implementations on the internet to redeem authorization codes etc...
I know the latest version of MSAL.NET will handle auto code redeem without writing any manual code but how to use it, any good example will help me a lot.

Second, what are the best practices followed while using MSAL.NET with authorization code flow to call my own API?

Note: I am using the .net framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to note when using MSAL.Net and the `ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code` is to make sure to disable the PKCE `UsePkce = false` as per [this Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.openidconnect.openidconnectoptions.usepkce?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

> PKCE standard. This only applies when the ResponseType is set to Code.

if you didn't you will get the below error when you try to `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode()`

> AADB2C90183: The supplied code_verifier is invalid

I used this sample code from Microsoft https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi and changed the `ResponseType`, `UsePkce` to false, `Scope`, the `Web.config` file and your good to go.

> Note: UsePkce has been introduced in *Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect* `4.2.0` if you don't want to upgrade your package but you still want to use `UsePkce = false`. you need to implement the `Notifications.RedirectToIdentityProvider` and remove the `code_challenge` and `code_challenge_method` from the `notification.ProtocolMessage.Parameters`.

I hope this save the a day from someone someday.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

Microsoft.Identity.Web adds extension methods that provide convenience services for calling Microsoft Graph or a downstream web API. These methods are explained in detail in A web app that calls web APIs: Call an API. With these helper methods, you don't need to manually acquire a token.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-acquire-token?tabs=aspnetcore
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

Also you can use custom solution like below
https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html

Answer (score 0):

Start reading from here, it supports the following frameworks:

1. .Net Core
2. .Net framework

For MVC ensure first that u are using either Asp.net Core or normal .net framework. Once you have figured that out. You can find the relevant code which you can refer to generate the token logic.

Read here for more details about the MSAL authentication library.

[MSAL authentication library for dot net](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/MSAL.NET-supports-multiple-application-architectures-and-multiple-platforms)

Code samples collection.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code